# How to open a camera in webview?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-camera

I have asked permission in my app

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Then in java i wrote:

```
 webview.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
         webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
         webview.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
```

I have load one url in webview :

```
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
  webview.loadUrl("https://demo.app/welcome");
```

In that url there are feature for take photo and upload image it is working fine in web but in my app in webview it i am unable to open camera or files.

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/mgks/Os-FileUp)

Comment: Okay ! Great !..

Comment: it is working for camera , images but not for video uploading can anyone tell me what i do for video uploading in webview?? @Piyush

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly open camera form a web view but you can get a video or image 
[follow this link](https://androidexample.com/Open_File_Chooser_With_Camera_Option_In_Webview_File_Option/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=128) if you want to upload the image on your page

Comment: are you using an emulator or mobile phone, if using a mobile phone then check your camera is working?